# UISearchDisplayController - how I can disable the automatic search

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

I use a `UISearchDisplayController` and I search a way to disable the automatic search.

Is there a way for that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903718/uisearchdisplaycontoller-cant-prevent-table-reload-on-typing-in-search-bar/5342989#5342989), which has a nice explanation of how this works. I thought about giving you the answer in a single line but I wanted to let you know more details so you can get a better idea of how it works?

Answer (score 4):

Implement the UISearchDisplayControllerDelegate method `-searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:` and return `NO`. When you want to reload the search table, call `[theSearchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData]`.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the automatic search in **UISearchDisplayController**

1) set **UISearchDisplayDelegate** to self

2) in **didShowSearchResultsTableView** delegate method

set the frame searchResultsTableView as

```
CGRect tempFrame= searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.frame;
tempFrame.size.height=0.0f;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.frame=tempFrame;
```