# iOS: Search suggestions as you type

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have a viewcontroller with a searchView and a tableView and I want the tableView to display results from a websearch based on the text of the searchView (changing as you add more letters to the search).

As I have it now, each time a letter is added it searches properly but the app stalls as it searches so you can't add in a new letter until the last results have returned.

Is there a smarter way to do this so that when a new letter is added the last search is essentially aborted?

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if(searchText.length>3)
    {
        [self getWebDataWithQuery:searchBar.text]
        [tblResults reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `[self getWebDataWithQuery:searchBar.text]` do?  Is it making a synchronous or asynchronous call?

Comment: It calls NSData dataWithContentsOfURL. Sorry I'm not super versed in this yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3903718/352891 explores the handling of the situation once you start making your data retrieval asynchronous

Comment: You need to do the calls asynchronously, and cancel them when you spawn a new one. AFNetworking can do network related things asynchronous for you. You could also look into NSOperation or its lower level counterpart, Grand Central Dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `[self getWebDataWithQuery:searchBar.text]` is calling `[NSData datawithContentsOfURL:]`.  That is a synchronous call.  You need to use an asynchronous mechanism to collect your data from the web service.  Either use a third party network framework such as AFNetworking or NSULRConnection.

This will allow the user to continue typing and will not block the UI.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't seem a good solution, because the user still have to wait that the data are loaded. It's better to download all the data, put inside an array of dictionaries or objects, and filter using a predicate. It's more user friendly ;-)

Comment: It would depend on the data.  If the dataset is large and is updated frequently, you would not want to download a fresh copy each time the app is launched.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but if the dataset is large, download a fresh copy at every search text change is even worst than loading it at the launch ;-) However, yes, if there is a lot of data, the array on which doing the filter should contain only the minimum data required to do that work!

Comment: You could limit the search response to a maximum of 10 or 15 items.  No need to download everything.

Comment: Yes, now I understand better what do you mean. It depends on the goal of the search: if you have a big dataset and want to search ALL the dataset (example: your mail inbox) it's better to send the query and let the server doing the search for you :-) If you want to search rapidly on a small subset of data (for example: a list of activities like my example, where "small" could even mean 1000-2000 activities) you can use a local search that is very good for the user interaction

Comment: I add: I think that if he wants a "server search" he should move it away from the textDidChange method...for that kind of search I prefer a "search" button, I prefer to use textDidChange only for the "fast local search".

Answer (score 1):

You could use a call like this in your search results

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self getWebDataWithQuery:searchBar.text]
       [tblResults reloadData]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar:

- on view controller load you load the data from web/database/core data
- put the data inside an array (the data can be objects or dictionaries), in my example is "arrayOfActivities"
- create a secondary array, let's call it "filteredArray" and copy all the content inside it

Then, at every digit, update the filtered array using a predicate.
This is good if you have a small dataset (you can even split your data in two arrays and permit the search only on a small subset, like the newest, for example)

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText;
{
    if (![searchText isEqualToString:@""]) // here you check that the search is not null, if you want add another check to avoid searches when the characters are less than 3
    {
        // create a predicate. In my case, attivita is a property of the object stored inside the array
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(attivita CONTAINS[cd] %@)", searchText];
        self.filteredArray = [[self.arrayOfActivities filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
    } else {
        self.filteredArray = [self.arrayOfActivities mutableCopy];  // I used a mutable copy in this example code
    }

    // reload section with fade animation
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it (I did it like this in one of my projects) I create an NSOperations  for the search. Every time a character from the search string was changed I checked if the last search query is not equal with the current, if it wasn't then I cancel all the executing operations and after that I create a new operation and start it.

Off course all the requests/data processing is performed in background thread and only when the downloading/parsing/processing is completed the UI is notified.